# Using the right URL for a website with runtime

Tags: java, url, runtime, yahoo-finance

I have an annoying problem. You see, I am writing a REALLY simple program that opens a few webpages for me. Well, the webpages I intend to open are all branches of http://finance.yahoo.com/, but the branches aren't working, as it just opens up to the main page. I am using this code for example to look at Goldman Sachs stocks:

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
r.exec("cmd /c start Chrome http://finance.yahoo.com/q
   p=http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fq%3Fs%3DGS%26ql%3D0&type=
2button&fr=uh3_finance_web&uhb=uh3_finance_vert&s=GS");
```

The URL is the static reference of the Goldman Sachs webpage of Yahoo Finance, so it should be working?

Comment: Use `ProcessBuilder`, separate each element of the command into an array `{"cmd", "/c", "start", "Chrome", "http://finance.yahoo.com/qp=http%3A%2F%2Ffinance.yahoo.com%2Fq%3Fs%3DGS%26ql%3D0&type=
2button&fr=uh3_finance_web&uhb=uh3_finance_vert&s=GS"}`

Comment: You should probably look into using `Desktop.getDesktop().browse(URL url);`

Comment: Also, that URL did not work for me in Firefox.  Are you sure it's right?